# login screen is not displayed

Tags: android, android-activity

Don't Close the question if you Don't have Ans/ Don't want to help stay away

**Hi app is not showing login Activity when its installed but when i clear cache and data in device and restart the app then it show login activity and after login it take me to the app**
but i want it to take me first to the login screen and once logged in then it only it should allow me to go directly to the main screen whenever it starts the app until it log out from it

> i have implemented double press back button as exit. Will that effect that login screen problem?

What is my mistake can anyone tell me

**Main Page**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);

    }
}
```

**Login Page**

```
public class LoginPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private Button loginbt;
    private EditText emailtxt, passwordtxt;
    private final String TAG = "LoginPage";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);

        emailtxt = findViewById(R.id.Usernamein);
        passwordtxt = findViewById(R.id.Passwordin);
        loginbt = findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);


        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        loginbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = emailtxt.getText().toString();
                String password = passwordtxt.getText().toString();
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter Email and Password",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginPage.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                    updateUI(user);
                                } else {
                                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }


                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null){
            updateUI(currentUser);
        }

    }

    public void updateUI(FirebaseUser currentUser){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);
        intent.putExtra("email", currentUser.getEmail());
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**MainFest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.crimerecords">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Add_Criminals"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainMenu"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainMenu"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginPage"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>


        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>



</manifest>
```

**Main Activity is a splash screen** after that it should take me to the login screen

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME_OUT=2000;
    //After completion of 2000 ms, the next activity will get started


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        //This method is used so that your splash activity
        //can cover the entire screen.

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        LoginPage.class);
                //Intent is used to switch from one activity to another.

                startActivity(i);
                //invoke the SecondActivity.

                finish();
                //the current activity will get finished.

            }

        }, SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME_OUT);

    }

}
```

Comment: Remove intent filter from main and add it in Login activity tag in manifest

Comment: Did it worked??

Comment: What do you mean by **"app is not showing login Activity when its installed"**?

Comment: Your previous question was closed because you have not defined your question well. It isn't clear what your problem is. Posting the exact same question again is likely going to get it closed again. Please reformulate your question so that we can help you. We don't close questions because we have no answers, we close questions that aren't readable or aren't clear. Begging people not to close your question isn't going to help you either as it is more likely to irritate someone. We are not paid consultants, we help because we want to help. **Note: I didn't close your question**

Comment: There are hundreds of tutorials on the Internet that explain how to create a login page for Android. You might scan a few of those tutorials and try some of those solutions before coming here looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all from your `SplashActivity` go-to `LoginActivity`. When users logged in make a `SharedPreference` and put a boolean value `true` and check it on your splash screen activity. If the user already logged in then the value is true. If the value is true go-to MainPage activity else go LogIn Activity.

For SharedPreference follow official doc [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)